# Cambiar tamaño de barra de estado QT

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Ando trabajando un poco con `QT` y ando modificando un poco los componentes (los `widgets`) de un código que me pasaron, dándoles color, poniendo iconos, etc. Sin embargo no encuentro el comando para `statusBar()` para hacer que la barra de estado sea ligeramente mas grande en cuestión de altura que su tamaño predeterminado.

Alguien me podría ayudar al respeto.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo suele ser atacar la hoja de estilos del componente. Prueba algo tal que:

```
statusBar()->setStyleSheet("height: 100");
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comentario, voy a usarlo, aunque lo que acabo de hacer es un archivo CSS y hacer una función que lo lea (el cual ya funciona) por lo que creo que ahora el comando quedaria de la siguiente forma supongo.

    statusbar
    {
      height; 100;
  }